# can not get url

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am getting an error message can not GET / on heroku and not sure why

I have tried to access diffrent web urls such as /api/user yet I am getting the same error

Here is the app on github https://github.com/rishipr/teams

Here is the app on heroku https://teams101.herokuapp.com/

Here are the routes on sever.js file

```
  // Routes
  app.use("/api/users", users);
  app.use("/api/projects", projects);
  app.use("/api/tasks", tasks);
```

What am I missing

Comment: You say you try to access `/api/user`, yet you show no route for that exact URL.  On the `users` router, your code indicates POST routes only for `/api/users/login` and `/api/users/register`.  I see no GET routes at all on that router.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250/

Comment: there is no route define for "/" hence you are getting that error, but if you try https://teams101.herokuapp.com/api/projects you get unauthorize. If you define ```app.get('/',(req,res)=>{...})``` in your server.js it will resolve that particular error